# Check Knockout.js with plain JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I have an existing project I need to edit. I'm experienced in plain JavaScript, but not so in Knockout and asp.net.

The following piece takes all values and displays them:

```
<!-- ko foreach: counter().list-->
    <span data-bind="text: count"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

So that I have something like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 etc.
```

How can I check for specific numbers and perform actions, based on the current number?
Like

```
if(count==1){
   console.log("one");
} else if(count==2){
   console.log("two");
} // etc...
```

So basically I would need to mix knockout.js with plain JS. Is this possible?

Comment: You'll do yourself a favor by first going through [the knockoutjs tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/), because as it stands your question is somewhat vague because you seem to be missing some basics.

Comment: Where do you want to do what? Can you make a more realistic sample of where and why would you use the code you're showing, and how your current ko viewmodel looks like?

Comment: Your question is not clear because we cannot see what you're trying to do. If you wanted to do different things based on a `count` var in javascript, then it looks like you should know this (although a `switch` statement might be better) since it's javascript, not knockout. Add some context

Answer (score 0):

You can do check using $index which is the index in turn on the loop

lets say you have an array of persons:

```
var people = [{name:'one'},{name:'two'},{name:'three'}];

<!-- ko foreach: people -->
    <!-- ko if: $index === 1 -->
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

In this case you use $index variable to only print the name for index 1 in your collection ('two'). Note that "name" property is set automatically in context for your loop.

Source 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html